# Is component communication in Angular JS using Rxjs Observables better than Input/Output or View child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, angular-components, angular2-observables

I know that it will depend on the use cases but just wanted the pros and cons from the community.
I have a tried all 3 methods and personally  I felt component communication using  Observables is better as your components are more loosely coupled this way. 
Although I felt a small delay while using Observables. 
Is it by design ? Or am I missing something. 
Will share code if anyone wants my implementation.